# I can't decode my own RSA message! (using java)

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger

So I want to use RSA encryption to encrypt some information for me but i cannot decode it sometimes after I am done. Here is my code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class rsa_practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigInteger p = new BigInteger("61");
        BigInteger q = new BigInteger("53");
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger("17");
        BigInteger n = p.multiply(q);
        BigInteger phi = p.subtract(new BigInteger("1")).multiply(q.subtract(new BigInteger("1")));
        BigInteger m = new BigInteger("22");    //24390, 1758
        BigInteger d = e.modInverse(phi);
        BigInteger c = m.modPow(e, n);
        BigInteger mAGAIN = c.modPow(d, n);

        System.out.println("" + c);
        System.out.println("" + mAGAIN);
    }
}
```

m should always equal mAGAIN but for some reason this isn't always the case for me. For example, if m is 22 or 1758, mAGAIN is 22 or 1758. However, if m is 24390, then mAGAIN is 1759 for some reason. I don't understand why encrypting and decrypting m changes its value when I am done. Any feedback or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because 24390 is larger than n (=3233). In fact 24390 % 3233 = 1759, so all is OK with your algorithm.

RSA only works if m < n.

Comment: I can't believe i forgot about that -_- Thank you so much!!